# Minimal delay when listing activities using the Reports API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I would like to use the [`list` method in the Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) to periodically fetch Activities of all users of some applications (e.g. 'admin' and 'login') and keep a local copy of all that data (using `watch` and push notifications is not an option in my particular scenario).

The idea is defining small time windows (e.g. 60 seconds) and, at the end of each time window plus some small delay, using the 'list' method and setting the `startTime` and `endTime` accordingly, fetching all events logged during the already finished time window.

This way I would be able to have an almost-real-time list of events locally stored. However, I'm not sure about what minimal delay should be used to ensure that the `list` method will be able to fetch all events. I'm assuming some delay is required here. Am I right? If so, is there any minimum delay that guarantees all events will be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you wouldn't need a delay, but probably 10 secs would be fine if you want to be sure. Another important thing would be the api quota, in this case the project would be limited to 5 queries per second. Here is the documentation on that https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/limits

Comment: I'm afraid some delay greater than 10 seconds is required. I've executed several tests and I found delays up to ~ 30 minutes (both to have an event available through `list` or to get the push notifications using `watch`). Slowest events during my tests were 'login' events, but I'm assume this depends a lot of the state of the internal Google infrastructure.